# Problema con NetBeans e Interfaces Graficas

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, interfaz-gráfica, windows10

es mi primera pregunta aquí. Pero no es la primer que se soluciona aquí.
El caso:
Llevo todo el curso usando **Netbeans 14 & JDK 18.0.2.1** acabamos de empezar a usar Interfaces graficas en Java. Cuando estoy trabajando en un proyecto que implica Interfaz Grafica, Netbeans se congela y no responde, puede pasar a los cinco minutos, o a la hora. Solo puedo cerrarlo desde el Administrador de tareas.
-La maquina virtual de java tiene 8 de 32 Gb asignados.
Al ejecutar Netbeans desde el CMD el mensaje que aparece es:

```
The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.
WARNING: package com.apple.eio not in java.desktop
WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop
WARNING: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk not in java.desktop
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager (file:/C:/Archivos%20de%20programa/NetBeans-15/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
```

He probado con Netbeans 14 & JDK 19.0.2, Netbeans 15 & JDK 18.0.2.1, pero siempre sale el mismo mensaje. Este mensaje aparece al mientras se Netbeans funciona, una vez que se congela no responde y no da ningún mensaje.
Uso Windows 10. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Los mensajes son advertencias, que no tienen que ver con tu problema, te sugiero que uses el programa con el medidor de recursos abierto (no recuerdo el nombre, hace años que no uso "W"), de esa manera podremos descartar que se cuelgue por un excesivo consumo de recursos.